# What is the best iOS Mobile Studio for my situation?

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, electronic-music

I am setting up a very small (mobile) studio so I can make music on my iPad. I am reading a lot about interfaces and other equipment but would like to keep it as simple as possible. So my question is, what do I actually need? I have up til now;

- iPad Pro 2020 11”
- Akai MPK Mini MK
- Bluetooth earphones

I am using KORG Gadget 2 and Garageband together with my MIDI keyboard. I would also like to start recording guitar to it. Do I basically just need a microphone for this and connect it to my iPad directly or do I need an interface (like the Focusrite 2i2) between it?

Hope somebody can help me! I don’t want to buy anything I don’t need..

Comment: To those voting to close the question, I'd like to point OP asks for _general_ equipment recommendation, not a _specific_ one.

Comment: Concerning recording guitar: what kind of guitar, electric, classical? Is recording with a microphone a must, or is recording directly via line in an option?

Comment: A classical, acoustic guitar so with a microphone will be a must